# Why getters don't have access to state in React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to get access to the component state from a getter, I noticed that `this` is set to a different context than in a normal method and therefore `this.state` doesn't work.

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tkaby7ks/

Why is that and how can I get access to the state from a getter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The point is that the getter is a property of the object you pass to `React.createClass`, not of the class that is created: react treats it as a value. From reacts perspective, the following 2 code snippets are exactly the same:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    foo: "asdf",
    ...
})
```

vs.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    get foo() { return "asdf" },
    ...
})
```

For functions that you pass to `createClass`, react binds the `this` variable to the component, but for getters it is not possible.

Comment: That makes total sense, thanks! Unfortunately this makes getters not very useful in React.

Comment: vdg, you could use Object.defineProperty in componentWillMount, it's just a very odd thing to do.  You should just use functions, which have the added bonus of being able to take arguments :-)